# Python instance method: same code two results

Tags: python, methods, interpreter

I am learning about Python instance, class and static methods so I  tried the following code:

```
class test (object):
   def testfunc():
      return 1

print(test.testfunc())
```

Since I am calling an instance method on the class itself and not on an instance of the class I was expecting to get a `TypeError`. However, when I executed this code on repl.it (an online compiler/interpreter/etc. which seems to use GCC 4.8.2) it simply returned 1.

I then tried the exact same code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php and got the expected `"TypeError: unbound method [...]"`.

What explains this difference?

Comment: it works fine in python 3.5 :/